# How to hide a part of Rails app from outsourced programmers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to hide a part of a Rails app from some developers? If not, how should I go about it?

(Background: We are thinking of outsourcing some part of the app to contractors, but worry they may copy the code we developed).

Comment: Did you think about mountable engines? Your contractor writes mountable engine and you just mount it to your main app.

Comment: Thanks jdoe. Could you explain more about mountable engine in a separate answer? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

that is always issue while outsourcing applications.
Here are my thoughts

> you can extract the secure business logic to a new app and host it some place secure,
>   another team can make REST calls to use the functionality
>
> you can create a gem also, but that is not secure another team can still see you code.

I Hope this helps you!